# What is the difference between class.method and object.method in Java and what are its cons and pros

Tags: java, swing, jpanel

```
OneClass.addComponentsToPane(onePanel);
pane.add(onePanel,c);

TwoClass two=new TwoClass();
two.addComponentsToPane(twoPanel);
pane.add(twoPanel,c);
```

1)Both class.method and object.method are working but what is the difference and(pros and cons?) where we have to use both

2)Where static variable and method is needed and where should be avoided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, you use static if you have a method or variable that is not connected with a specific instance of the class.

Assume you have class Sheep and a few objects of this class. You could use a static int variable to count all the sheep. So you could think of a static variable as something pertaining to the class (e.g. number of its instances) rather than to specific objects of this class.

When it comes to methods it's similar, e.g. class Math has many static methods, since when you do calculations it has nothing to do with any specific objects, results depend only on arguments.

A reason to use static would be when you want some values or methods used globally in your application.

Answer (score 0):

A class method (static) does actions on the class itself, which means that there can only be one instance in the entire JVM affected (barring some extraneous, irrelevant cases)>

A instance method (non-static) does actions on an object, meaning you can have many instances in the JVM affected.

It's good practice of Object-Oriented programming to use instance methods over class methods.

You can read the [Java tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html) on static to find out more if you want to.

Comment: Why is it good practice to use instance methods over class methods? That really depends on the situation. I would even say that it would be better to use class methods over instance methods if possible.

Comment: if static method is barring some extraneous, then when we have to use static method any example or situation?

Comment: I said good practice for object-oriented programming. Static methods have not objects, therefore are not object-oriented.

Comment: @Strikeskids what are you talking about? Of course it's still object-oriented even though it's a static method. Stop trying to dig an even deeper hole than the one you're already standing in :-) Give up, call it a day ;-)

Answer (score 0):

**Instance** (object) methods use an instance of a class, whereas a **Class** (static) method can be used with just the class name.

Typically you will use an instance method when you are creating some kind of a data model object and the operations on that model,whereas you will use static method just like you would in functional programming paradigm language.